# JQuery width, outerWidth ignores content width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div`, not specified any size inside CSS. Size grows with content using `display: inline-block`. Using width, outerWidth ignores the content size and returns zero. No need for an example, nothing special except I load my content with ajax `$.load`.

Content is definitely loaded before using `width`. Somebody with a hint?

Comment: Can you provide an example recreating the problem so we can try to help you?

Comment: Here is a simple example showing `outerWidth` working on an `inline-block` item: http://jsfiddle.net/G4wEh/

Comment: "No need for an example"? I think we need an example.

Comment: I don't understand your question, it would be better if you give an example. Try using `min-width`,`max-width` properties. you can also try `width:auto;`

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016307/force-reflow-in-css-transitions-in-bootstrap