# Any hidden advantage of assigning a variable to itself in javascript? "force reflow"?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I was doing code inspection on a js code base and I got some variables assigned to their-selves. I found one strange assignment in ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js:445 which is:

```
nextSlide.$element[0].offsetWidth = nextSlide.$element[0].offsetWidth; //force reflow
```

What they mean with the note: ***`// force reflow`*** ?

In general, is there any advantage of variable self-assignment in JS ? DOM nodes?

Comment: Possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21664940/1903116

Comment: Note that this isn't just variable assignment, it's a property on a DOM node, something quite different from `var a = 1; a = a;`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, I just notice that

Comment: As @thefourtheye and the note says, forcing a reflow in the browser render pipeline. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/?hl=en. And no, there are no advantages besides forcing reflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about reflow in [Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)

Essentially a 'reflow' is something that initiates a 'layout' update in the browsers render model. This can be useful if you know that a change has occurred that should require the page to be re-rendered, but for some reason this might not have happened.

Specifics about what can or should cause a reflow, or when the layout will actually be recalculated, are down to each browser implementation. From the article linked above:

> Since the reflows and repaints associated with render tree changes are
>   expensive, the browsers aim at reducing the negative effects. [...]. The
>   browser will setup a queue of the changes your scripts require and
>   perform them in batches.

So you may find a situation where you are expecting a reflow/layout to have occurred, but the browsers layout batch policy has prevented it from occurring (yet). This seems to be what the original code is trying to solve.

Comment: *for some reason this might not be obvious to the browser* What would be an example of such a reason?

Comment: Historically we've seen buggy implementations where it's been necessary to force a repaint in the browser too.  They've certainly got a lot better though.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is also used sometimes to refresh web pages, example :

```
// refresh the current web page 
document.location.href = document.location.href;
```

Or used to redraw [HTML5 canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element), for example :

```
// .. draw some pretty cool shapes here 
// force canvas to redraw
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

Hope this helps.