# JavaScript: Trigger CSS Transition with window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, transition, setinterval

This is (obviously) part of a bigger project, but I am trying to trigger a CS transition on `setTimeout`.

(I know about using CSS animations, but this is not just about repeated transitions).

A CSS transition will occur when a property changes. For my own purposes, I use `setAttribute` as that isolates the behaviour from other class-related stuff, but the behaviour below works the same.

Assuming the HTML and other code is in place, here is simplified version:

```
var test=document.querySelector('div#test');    
window.setInterval(doit,4000);
function doit() {
    test.removeAttribute('thing');
    test.innerHTML=new Date();
    test.setAttribute('thing',null);
}
```

The CSS is:

```
div#test {
    opacity: 0;
}
div#test[thing] {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The trick I am trying is to change clear the attribute and then set it again — that should trigger the CSS change. It doesn’t work as above. However, *if I delay setting the attribut by 0 seconds*, it does work:

```
function doit() {
    test.removeAttribute('thing');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        test.setAttribute('thing',null);
    },0);
    test.innerHTML=new Date();
}
```

The question is: why does it not work unless I add this minuscule delay, and is there a better way to do this?

I would like an answer *without* jQuery.

Note: I have accepted an answer below. The following code will work:

```
function doit() {
    test.removeAttribute('thing');
    test.offsetHeight;                  //  force update
    test.innerHTML=new Date();
    test.setAttribute('thing',null);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to change the URL with location (this was with angular but i think thats just a wrapper anyways). I changed the location.search values and redirected the page directly after. When using the "back" function in the browser the last page did not reflect the changed "search" parameter if i didn't put the redirect inside a timeout. I don't know why but it seems like it's the way it is, haven't found a good answer for it anywhere at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the browser queues reflow and relayout changes. The browser *does not* do these things sequentially like how you've structured your code. It adds the changes to a queue and attempts to perform multiple operations at once (for performance reasons).

The browser is trying to be "smart" here - it sees that the styles are going to wind up exactly as they were before, so the removal and re-addition of the attribute are batched together in one update and thus you see no change. Adding the `setTimeout`, even with a 0 second delay, forces the browser to reflow at that point.

Here's a link to another similar question: [Force browser to trigger reflow while changing CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css)

And here's a comprehensive list of methods/properties you can call in JS to force a reflow in your JS (instead of using `setTimeout`):
https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question to include a simple solution. The two links you included were also excellent.