# Div appears even when cookie policy is still in date

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code below is supposed to set a cookie with a 60 day expiration date when a button is clicked, which works Ok, but when I open the site in another window or refresh the page, the div still appears, I'm unable to find out why.

Can anyone stop what I have wrote wrong

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var cookieAlert = document.querySelector(".cookiealert");
    var acceptCookies = document.querySelector(".acceptcookies");

    cookieAlert.offsetHeight; // Force browser to trigger reflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39451131)

    if (!getCookie("acceptCookies")) {
       cookieAlert.classList.add("show");
    }

    acceptCookies.addEventListener("click", function () {
        setCookie("acceptCookies", true, 60);
        cookieAlert.classList.remove("show");
    });
})();

// Cookie functions stolen from w3schools
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === " ") c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Here is the HTML that I'm using

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible text-center cookiealert show" role="alert">
    <div class="cookiealert-container">
        @privacyText <a href="@privacyLink">Learn more</a>

        <button id="btnCookiePolicy" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm acceptcookies" aria-label="Close">
            I agree
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong...

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible text-center cookiealert show" role="alert">
```

You need to remove the class `show` from the class list, as you want the dialog to be hidden by default, and then you add the `show` class if there is no cookie.

Just change that line to this...

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible text-center cookiealert" role="alert">
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Archer, forgot I hard coded that in to test, I think I need a rest

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes you do just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it for you :).