# I have this code to modify but not understand the second statement in if block

Tags: javascript

the second statement in the block if which is `$next.addclass(type).offsetWidth` is neither a call to a function neither an assignment.

```
if (transition) 
{ 
$next.addClass(type);
$next[0].offsetWidth; 
}
else 
{  
$active.removeClass('active');
$next.addClass('active');
}
```

What's the logic here?

Comment: If $next[0] is undefined, that line will raise an error. Maybe that's the logic, just a deceived assertion, preventing the script to continue if $next[0] is not set.

Comment: some properties are only calculated when the code tries to access them (say, on a delayed layout situation), that might be the logic too,

Comment: @Sergeon That would be a very stupid way of doing an assertion, I really doubt anyone would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offsetWidth` is a measurement property that must be calculated and accessing it will cause a [DOM reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow). This would be the only possible use of reading an unused value. Otherwise it's just dead code.

The code should probably have been:

```
if (transition) { 
    $next.addClass(type);
    forceDomReflowFrom($next[0]);
} else {  
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $next.addClass('active');
}

function forceDomReflowFrom(el) {
    el.offsetWidth;
}
```

Here's another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css) where this approach was used to force a browser reflow (otherwise CSS animations wouldn't work).

Comment: Best answer so far! Thank you very much :)