# How can I display an element and animate it using CSS transitions deterministically?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser, css-animations

**I'm attempting to add an element to the DOM that's in an invisible state, and then animate it in.**

Specifically:

- I add an element to the DOM with the following inline styles: `transition: all 200ms linear`
- I measure the element for positioning reasons using `getBoundingClientRect` (this is done before the element actually becomes visible)
- I set `transform: scale(0)`, which is the initial animation state
- Next, I access the element's `offsetHeight` property in order to force a DOM reflow (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css)): `void(elem.offsetHeight)`. This is done to have the applied styles actually take effect.
- To display and animate the element, I set `transform: scale(1)`

**The expected result is for the element to pop in with a nice animation.**  Everything works as expected when I have the devtools open in Firefox. When the dev tools are closed, the element doesn't animate at all about 80% of the time. In Chrome, the animations always work as expected.

**Something about having the Firefox devtools open causes the elements to animate in deterministally.** I suspect that the additional overhead, or perhaps additional querying of the DOM, is the causing the desired behavior when the devtools are open.

**How do I get this to work deterministically?**

I've tried adding the animated properties in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback to no avail, and have stopped short of accepting `setTimeout` as an acceptable solution due to the perceived input latency it would introduce, and the fact that it's a gross hack.

Comment: nothing to do with the question but since the element is scaled to 0, why setting display to none ?

Comment: I've updated the question to more accurately resemble what I'm doing

Comment: Can you add a simple version of your code to this post, ideally as a runnable snippet? Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing it in action. (That said, you may want to look into the `TransitionEvent` types available - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend and friends. Not sure if it addresses your problem, but it might.)

Comment: I appreciate the advice! I'll put together an isolated reproduction and update the question some time tomorrow.

Comment: Better than forcing a DOM reflow, it's to set the CSS change on a timeout