# Proper timeout for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, settimeout

I know that CSS transitions do not work with `auto` keyword, so if I want to apply `transition: left 2s, right 2s;` have to vary both right and left from (let's say) *0* to *100*.

I have a script which might change an object's position either towards left or right, but I cannot set `right: 100` if `left` is set to `0` (it has to be `auto`).

So I came out with this solution.

```js
function moveObject(direction) {
    direction ? myobject.style.right = 0 : myobject.style.left = 0;    //same position as auto but can be transitioned
    direction ? myobject.style.right = "50vw" : myobject.style.left = "50vw";    //actual transition
}

function resetObject() {
    myObject.style.left = myObject.style.right = "auto";   //now I can move to either right or left again
    //I don't need an animation on reset
}
```

```css
#myobject {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    
    /*width, height...*/
}
```

```html
<div id="myObject"></div>
```

This didn't work (the assign to `0` was completely ignored).

So I came out with this solution instead (same as above but using `setTimeout(..., 0);`

```js
function moveObject(direction) {
    direction ? myobject.style.right = 0 : myobject.style.left = 0;

    setTimeout(function() {
        direction ? myobject.style.right = "50vw" : myobject.style.left = "50vw";    //this is executed async
    }, 0);
}

function resetObject() {
    myObject.style.left = myObject.style.right = "auto";
}
```

```css
#myobject {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    
    /*width, height...*/
}
```

```html
<div id="myObject"></div>
```

This improved the result, but sometimes (it seems to be completely random, but more frequently on small screens), the transition still does not occur.

I supposed that this was because of the fact that sometimes the asynchronous function is executed too soon, so I tried to increase the delay to *10ms*, but the problem still occurs sometimes (less frequently).

Now, I could increase the value furthermore, but:

- I can never be sure that the error will not occur anyway sooner or later, maybe on a faster device (unless I set the timeout to a very large number)
- I cannot set the timeout to a very large number, since I want it to be imperceptible

So, is there a minimum number that can assure a successful output?

If not, how can accomplish the same result?

Comment: You need to force trigger the css changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css/21665117

Comment: @Akxe7 thank you very much! I can't test it now but it seems to be exactly what I need... I'll let you know as soon as I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akxe suggested, the solution was reflowing the page. In other words, browsers flush multiple changes of the DOM all together. This speeds up the page by a bit but leads to some problems like the one I described ([further information here](https://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/))

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css/21665117), the solution was a function like this one:

```js
function reflow() {    //this will be called between the two elements
    void(document.documentElement.offsetWidth);
}

function moveObject(direction) {
    direction ? myobject.style.right = 0 : myobject.style.left = 0;
    reflow();   //the line above is now flushed
    direction ? myobject.style.right = "50vw" : myobject.style.left = "50vw";
}

function resetObject() {
    myObject.style.left = myObject.style.right = "auto";
}
```

```css
#myobject {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    
    /*width, height...*/
}
```

```html
<div id="myObject"></div>
```

The function actually worked for me even without using [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), but I preferred keeping it since in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css/21665117) someone pointed out that it didn't work for him, and also for more clarity.

[This](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) could also be useful: it is an (unofficial) list of everything that causes page reflow.