How to await rendering of visible DOM changes?
If we have some browser JS code that does a lot of computation, how to reliable yield to allow the browser do some rendering inbetween, eg. we want to display progress indicators? I tried awaiting requestAnimationFrame handler, but that - for at least in Chromium - does not always allow rendering to happen.
Example:
...compute...

statusElement.innerText = 'were almost done!';
await new Promise(resolve => window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

...compute...

does often, but not always show "were almost done" until the second computation is completed and the JS code exits.
So is there any canonical way to make sure this DOM change is visible before proceeding?

Use a Web Worker?

@ivar he is asking about DOM changes visibility

@underscore Yes, I know. If you use a Web Worker, and post messages to update the UI, then the DOM changes aren't an issue.

Does this have anything to do with forcing a layout reflow?  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css

@James Forcing a reflow does not necessarily cause rendering/painting the screen

The requestAnimationFrame callback is called just before the next repaint. It is with the next call of requestAnimationFrame that you make once that callback is called, that you can schedule a new callback to execute after that repaint, and before the next one. So it is only when the second callback executes (given to the second call of requestAnimationFrame) that a repaint has already executed since your modifications.
So I woud suggest awaiting this promisified requestAnimationFrame at the very start of your heavy-processing function, and then do that again at a later point.
Demo:


const beforePaint = () => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);

const busyLoop = delay => { 
    const stop = performance.now() + delay; 
    while (performance.now() < stop) {
    }
}

async function heavyTask(statusElement) {
    await beforePaint(); // <-- add one of these at the very start
    // Here the first paint since the call of `heavyTask` has not yet occurred.
    statusElement.innerText = '0%';
    await beforePaint(); // during the awaiting the first paint will happen
    // Here we can be sure that "0%" has rendered
    busyLoop(300);
    statusElement.innerText = '30%';
    await beforePaint();
    busyLoop(100);
    statusElement.innerText = '40%';
    await beforePaint();
    busyLoop(200);
    statusElement.innerText = '60%';
    await beforePaint();
    busyLoop(300);
    statusElement.innerText = '90%';
    await beforePaint();
    busyLoop(100);
    statusElement.innerText = '100%';
}

heavyTask(document.querySelector("div"));
<div></div>



If you remove that first await beforePaint();, then you may not see "0%" being displayed, for the reason explained.

I see.. So for to make sure a certain reportProgress will always work independent of where it is inserted, it has to await two animation frames - one before and one after the DOM change?

Yes, that is the essence of it. But if you have a sequence of chunks to render, then you don't need to double the awaiting of animation frames. You just need one more than what intuition might tell you: and place it at the very beginning.
