# jQuery: check if a dynamically loaded div is rendered

Tags: jquery

I create a div dynamically and then should change css properties based on the width of that div:

```
function test(divID){
    //some actions - creating the div 'tbl' structure
    $('#'+divID).html(tbl); 
    var tw = $('#'+divID).width() + 80;
    $('.page').css("width", tw+"px");   
}
```

It all works fine in Chrome, but not very stable in FF - sometimes it calculates var tw before the div is rendered and returns its zero width.

How can I sync these events, i.e. measure the width of that div after it has been rendered? I cannot use onLoad, because the whole DOM is loaded before that.

Thanks

Comment: A quick hack around it would be to put the code after the `.html` call in a `setTimeout` with timeout 0

Comment: You may consider using the mutation framework.. that works as an observer design pattern and gives you a notification whenever a node is added to the dom tree..

Comment: Also you can try using native js $('#'+divID)[0].innerHTML = tbl; maybe this would help make things faster and more stable.

Comment: The setTimeout hack works - I set 20ms time, but we cannot be sure it will be enough for all end-user browsers. Using native js makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a reflow of content (making sure the new content is in the DOM) by calling for the `offsetWidth` on an object.

Here your code would look like:

```
function test(divID){
    //some actions - creating the div 'tbl' structure
    $('#'+divID).html(tbl); 
    $('.page')[0].offsetWidth; // force reflow;
    var tw = $('#'+divID).width() + 80;
    $('.page').css("width", tw+"px");   
}
```

You wouldn't want to do this in a huge loop as page reflows are relatively expensive operations. instead, you could run a loop that creates divs, then call `offsetWidth`, then another loop to assign widths.

See ["Force Reflow" in CSS transitions in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016307/force-reflow-in-css-transitions-in-bootstrap) for more info.

Comment: I guess, "Force Reflow" should be before measuring the width and not after, right?

Comment: Doesn't work, regardless of the position of the "force reflow" - before or after width measurement. It simple returns width zero as the DOM has not been rendered.